# Finite group with at least 3 generators?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The answer to this question could be trivial, but usually I do not work in group theory.

> Is there a  finite nonabelian group $G$ that is generated by $S$ where $S$ is a minimal generating set of $G$, and $3\leq |S|\leq |G|-1$? (Other than the direct product of nonabelian or abelian groups)

What I'm looking here is **finite** nonabelian group that satisfies the above inquality. Of course
the obvious answer is the direct product of certain finite nonabelian or abelian  group, but I'm  not interested in it.

For the infinite nonabelian groups we can take the [free group of n-generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) (with n≥3).

I notice most of the finite nonabelian groups  like dihedral, symmetric group,.. does not satisfy the above condition.

Any help will be useful!

Comment: The nonabelian group $G=S_3$ is generated by the set $S=\{(1\ 2),(1\ 3),(2\ 3)\}.$ Did you leave out some condition you wanted?

Comment: @bof It seems clear that a minimal generating set is sought for.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That was my guess too, but I really like people to say what they mean.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Although, if he means minimal generating set, the inequalit $|S|\le|G|-1$ seems redundant.

Comment: @M.Badaoui If you really think $\;S_3\;$ is an excellent example, and thus you didn't mean a minimal set of generatorts, then ANY non-abelian group (of order greater than $\;5\;$, of course) will do.

Comment: @bof I agree that the formulation is somewhat vague. I think the "correct" question should be to ask for an example of an indecomposable finite group which cannot be generated by $2$ elements.

Comment: I'm just looking for a group with the the above property.

Comment: Then I just have to ask: Why would you be looking for an example of any indecomposable group with at least $3$ elements?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft For direct application in graph thoery (cayley graph)

Comment: I meant more along the lines of: How were you not already familiar with plenty of examples?

Comment: Any non-abelian simple group can be generated by two elements, so if you want an example that contains no direct product the closest I can think of is a semidirect product...

Comment: @Joanpemo Thank you for your help!

Comment: Actually, in the current formulation (and with these comments), your claim that the dihedral groups do not satisfy it is wrong.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Could you please be more specific about how the dihedral group  satisfy the condition?

Comment: The dihedral groups are not direct products, but they are clearly generated by the set of their elements apart from the neutral element.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes but the generating set S  have two elements.

Comment: There is no such thing as *the* generating set for a group. You were explicitly asked if you were looking for a minimal generating set, and you said no. You also said that $S_3$ was a good example, even though that is in fact a dihedral group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft  My bad, I modify the question.

Comment: But you have still written "the minimal generating set". The word "the" in English implies uniqueness, and minimal generating sets are not usually unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example of order $16$ which is not  a direct product, namely the central product of $D_8$ (dihedral of order $8$) and $C_4$.

Answer (score 0):

What about $\;Q_8\times C_2\;,\;\;Q_8=$ the quaternion group?

Comment: The answer is correct, but it is the direct product of two groups the case which is not included in question.

Comment: Well, it is the direct product of only one non-abelian group.